# Two False in while loop

Tags: python

I want someone who can help me with the python code. In this case I'm looking the peak on the left and right site.

I would like to that when `h[x+1] < h[x]` then `x = x-1` and `summit=False`. I'm trying write a second loop but this solution doesn't work.

Below is my code:

```
import math
import random                                                
                                                                             
w = [random.random()/3, random.random()/3, random.random()/3]
h = [1.+math.sin(1+x/6.)*w[0]+math.sin(-.3+x/9.)*w[1]+math.sin(-.2+x/30.)*w[2] for x in range(100)]
h[0] = 0.0; h[99] = 0.0

print(h)

def climb(x, h):
    # keep climbing until we've found a summit
    summit = False

    # edit here
    while not summit:
        summit = True         
        if h[x + 1] > h[x]:
            x = x + 1        
            summit = False    
        else: 
            if h[x + 1] < h[x]:
                x = x - 1         
                #summit = False 
            #summit = False 
    return x


def main(h):

    # start at a random place                                                                                    
    x0 = random.randint(1, 98)
    x = climb(x0, h)

    print("Venla started at %d and got to %d" % (x0, x))
    return x0, x

main(h)
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but the else statement in your while loop, I think it is meant to say `h[x - 1]`?

Comment: Hey Jax Teller i short-circuit this stage and now i have
```while not summit:
        summit = True         # stop unless there's a way up
        if h[x + 1] > h[x]:
            x = x + 1         # right is higher, go there
            summit = False    # and keep going
        else:
            x = x - 1         # right is higher, go there
                #summit = False 
            #summit = False 
    return x```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier not to handle the index counting yourself but let [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) do that for you. Then loop over all values and leave the function if you found a value that satisfies the requirements.

```
def climb(x, h):
    for idx, value in enumerate(h):
        if h[idx-1] < value and value > h[idx+1]:
            return idx
```

There is no boundary checking, so we assume that a summit can be found in the data.

Comment: The most important point is to understand how `enumerate` works. Everything else should be self-explanatory.